# Logstash email output plugin configuration error?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Using below config i am sending the logs to my email using logstash:

```
    output {
    email {
      to => "xyz@gmail.com"
      codec => "plain"
      contenttype => "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
      body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}"
      options => {
  smpt => {
    smtpIporHost => "smtp.gmail.com"
    port => 567
    userName => "user@gmail.com"
    password => "mypass"
    starttls => true
  }
}
    }

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is pretty clear:

> Unknown setting 'options' for email

You need to configure your [`email` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-outputs-email.html) like this instead:

```
email {
  to => "xyz@gmail.com"
  codec => "plain"
  contenttype => "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{message}"
  address => "smtp.gmail.com"
  port => 587
  username => "xyz@gmail.com"
  password => "passw"
  use_tls => true
}
```

Comment: Well, the original issue is resolved and now you're hitting another one, which is that Gmail doesn't accept your connection on port 587. Can you try `smtp-relay.gmail.com` instead?

Comment: For this issue you want to me raise a new question?

Comment: Well, considering that the initial issue is solved and we shouldn't cram too much into a single question, I'd say yes.